# Add more service-worker functionality with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, indexeddb, service-worker, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

So create-react-app includes service worker functionality [by default](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#making-a-progressive-web-app), which is lovely - all my static assets get cached for offline use out of the box. Cool, but now I want to take things a bit further and use indexedDB to cache some dynamic content.

Problem is, there's no service-worker.js file to modify. It gets generated during the build process.

Is there a way to add additional logic without ejecting create-react-app or redoing all the nice static caching stuff?

Comment: AFIK you'll have to eject your app before you can edit it's `service-worker`

Comment: Try [Using Sass with Create React App (Without Ejecting)](https://hackernoon.com/using-sass-with-create-react-app-without-ejecting-b5f4f827ed9e), you can also follow [this post by medium.com](https://medium.com/@kitze/configure-create-react-app-without-ejecting-d8450e96196a) for additional details about Sass. For details about Sass, [here is some site](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html) you can add on your research.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you've observed, `create-react-app`'s config is locked down, and the service worker logic is entirely defined in the config.

If you'd rather not `eject` but you want some customization, another option is to modify the `create-react-app` build process to explicitly call the `sw-precache` CLI *after* the normal build has completed, overwriting the `service-worker.js` that `create-react-app` generates by default. Because this involves modifying your local `package.json`, it doesn't require `eject`ing first.

There's some info on this approach [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/3132#issuecomment-330610440), and the general idea is modifying your `npm` scripts to look something like:

```
"build": "react-scripts build && sw-precache --config=sw-precache-config.js"
```

With `sw-precache-config.js` [configured](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-precache#options-parameter) based on your needs, but including

```
swFilePath: './build/service-worker.js'
```

to ensure that the built-in `service-worker.js` is overwritten.

Comment: Ahaa... Thanks, Jeff. This looks promising. So using this approach, how would I then get my own code into the service-worker.js file? Looking at the sw-precache docs, perhaps something like the importScripts option? sw-toolbox looks promising also... am I on the right track?

Comment: Actually @Jeff, I just watched your [talk from ChromeDevSummit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=DtuJ55tmjps) about [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/). Looks awesome. Wonder if I can use something like `"build": "react-scripts build && workbox-cli generate:sw --config-file=workbox-config.js"` to override the service-worker.js file?

Comment: Yup, definitely. You could do that as well.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9141

Comment: Hey jef, do you know how to combine two service-workers? I wanted to add notification capabilities to the PWA, but there isn't much resources tell how to to it.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and without doing `eject`, I could replace the default `service-worker` with `workbox`-generated one to add runtime caching webfonts, api calls, etc.

1. install `workbox-build`
2. prepare `src/sw-template.js` to add your `registerRoute` calls
3. prepare `/build-sw.js` to copy workbox file to 'build' folder and `injectManifest`
4. modify `package.json` scripts to run above `build-sw.js`
5. modify `src/registerServiceWorker.js` to replace the default one

You can find [detailed file changes here](https://github.com/bob-lee/react-joanne/pull/4/files).