# How do I exclude url's from service worker scope in create react app, without having to eject?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

I need a way to exclude URLs from a service-worker scope in create-react-app without having to eject. The service-worker is being generated and I cannot see any way how I could change this functionality without having to eject.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add more service-worker functionality with create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47636757/add-more-service-worker-functionality-with-create-react-app)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting service worker to exclude certain urls only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663796/setting-service-worker-to-exclude-certain-urls-only)

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution.

Create a script outside of the `src/` directory called `rebuild-service-worker.js`, with the following contents:

```js
"use strict";
const FS = require("fs");
let text = FS.readFileSync("./build/service-worker.js").toString();
const start = text.indexOf("blacklist: [");
const end = text.indexOf("\n", start) - 2;
text = text.substring(0, end) + ",/^\\/admin/" + text.substring(end);
FS.writeFileSync("./build/service-worker.js", text);
```

As you can see, it adds a new item to the `blacklist: []` array that is part of the Workbox configuration.

Then, in your `package.json` `build` script, simply call it after `react-scripts build` like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build && node ./rebuild-service-worker",
    ...
```