# How can i exclude some urls from service worker with create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app

I have app using create-react-app and service-worker generated on-a-build.

I checked out a lot of issues and articles, but still not found usable answer.

What is a best practice to add something like urlBlockList to create-react-app service worker?

---

I think `react eject` is not the most appropriate solution

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663796/setting-service-worker-to-exclude-certain-urls-only ?

Comment: yes, but service-worker code contains very clear phrase "do not modify this generated code", that is why i think - it's not best practice way. btw it is minified

Comment: I automated modification of the build/service-worker.js code after the create-react-app build process here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776235/how-do-i-exclude-urls-from-service-worker-scope-in-create-react-app-without-ha/63344095#63344095

Should be fine. Nothing is going to be modifying that file after it's released to production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved

Best solution that I found - use https://github.com/liuderchi/sw-precache-cra
and add unwanted urls to custom sw-config

*Example:*

```
// sw-config.js
module.exports = {
  runtimeCaching: [
    {
      urlPattern: '/unwantedurl',
      handler: 'networkFirst',
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that works with CRA 3:

1. Add [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) to your project, e.g.: `yarn add react-app-rewired --save-dev`
2. Replace `react-scripts` in the `scripts` section of your `package.json` with `react-app-rewired`
3. Place a file called `config-overrides.js` in the root of your project. In this file you can add entries to the service-worker configuration. For example:

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  const swPrecacheConfig = config.plugins.find(
     plugin => plugin.constructor.name === "GenerateSW"
  );
  // Prevent some URLs from being cached by the service worker
  const blacklist = swPrecacheConfig.config.navigateFallbackBlacklist;
  blacklist.push(/\/oauth2\/authorization\//);
  blacklist.push(/\/login\/oauth2\//);
  return config;
};
```

The configuration above excludes urls with `/oauth2/authorization/` and `/login/oauth2/` from the service-worker.